# Replace html code in a string with empty string in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I haven't done PHP programming since 4-5 years the last time I've had my PHP was like 2016 or 2017. I'm having trouble with this very simple problem.

I have this string. Now please do take note not to remove even one space cause it's very important.

```
$s = 'Congratulations, you completed the quiz!
<h2>{{result-title}}</h2>
{{result-text}}

You achieved {{points}} points from {{questions}} questions.\n\n
        <div class="chained-quiz-email">
                <form method="POST">
                <p><label>Your email address:</label> <input type="email" name="chained_email_844640736"
                
                id="chainedUserEmail" class="chained-quiz-email " required></p>
    
     <input type="submit" id="submit-email" value="Submit" name="submit-email-btn844640736">
     </form>
            
            
            </div>
        
        ';
```

Now I just wanted to remove this part of html code.

```
    <div class="chained-quiz-email">
            <form method="POST">
            <p><label>Your email address:</label> <input type="email" name="chained_email_844640736"
            
            id="chainedUserEmail" class="chained-quiz-email " required></p>

 <input type="submit" id="submit-email" value="Submit" name="submit-email-btn844640736">
 </form>
        
        
        </div>
```

The **output** would be like:

```
Congratulations, you completed the quiz!
<h2>{{result-title}}</h2>
{{result-text}}

You achieved {{points}} points from {{questions}} questions.
```

I was thinking of doing it with regular expression since I think it might be very useful.
I've come up with this pattern and still doesn't seem to work `$pattern = '/<div class="chained-quiz-email">.*?</div>/i';` I'm getting a return of an empty string. Can someone help me with this. I appreciate it!

Comment: simple explode would suffice, https://3v4l.org/0OhlD

Comment: `$pattern = '/<div class="chained-quiz-email">.*?</div>/i';` – almost there … the `/` needs to be escaped, because you are already using that as delimiter, and you need to use the `s` modifier, so that `.` matches newlines as well. https://regex101.com/r/oxtVpC/1

Comment: @LawrenceCherone  add that an answer. It looks good

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Oh! that's a good answer but I haven't mentioned about possibilities of having `\n\n` in the first part of the string but thanks let me just look onto it.

Comment: There could be a chance that something like this `Congratulations, \n\n you completed the quiz!
<h2>{{result-title}}</h2>
{{result-text}}`

But let me see first depending on a situation I'll have to look onto.

Comment: @IceBear  in that case use CBroe code

Comment: then change \n\n to something like `||` and do the split or on output remove it, though is xy as if you can change the string, simply remove it or do a condition on it not to add it, or add it as a template `{{form}}` and then whatever is rendering it out change so if form not defined doesn't output a value for it

Comment: Greetings people! Lawrence! Thank you, your answer is fine but I think the safest way is the regex provided by CBroe and Thank you too! It works well. I apologize I haven't been coding with PHP and I've been coding with python (brain's kind of tired and wire to a programming language that is so space sensitive). It seems there are differences tho

Comment: Anyway I think CBroe's answer is the best fit but still Lawrence's answer solves it too but I'm not just sure of the `\n\n` cases but it's perfect too. Could have thought of it earlier. But I think I'm just thinking of solving it the regex way. I think you can submit your answers as I can up and check :) Also never knew about this regex101.com site. Really useful.

Comment: hello! @CBroe  I think you should post your answer as this might be helpful to others. Same as to Lawrence. Thanks! or should I do it in your behalf guys?

Comment: Feel free to do it yourself. My comment was only minor corrections to what you already had anyway.

Comment: Oh Okay thanks! I'll do that cause I also make these as my notes as well. Whenever I want to get back to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added some configuration on the regular expression.

**From**

```
$pattern = '/<div class="chained-quiz-email">.*?</div>/i';
```

**Change it to:**

```
$pattern = '/<div class="chained-quiz-email">.*?<\/div>/is';
```

Explanation you can look it up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66776786/replace-html-code-in-a-string-with-empty-string-in-php?noredirect=1#comment118041613_66776786)

Also a very helpful [site](https://regex101.com/r/oxtVpC/1) to experiment on regular expressions.

Credits to @CBroe & @Lawrence (who has another alternative solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66776786/replace-html-code-in-a-string-with-empty-string-in-php?noredirect=1#comment118041591_66776786))

Answer (score 1):

You can use built-in php function strip_tags().

```
<?php
$s = 'Congratulations, you completed the quiz!
<h2>{{result-title}}</h2>
{{result-text}}

You achieved {{points}} points from {{questions}} questions.\n\n
        <div class="chained-quiz-email">
                <form method="POST">
                <p><label>Your email address:</label> <input type="email" name="chained_email_844640736"
                
                id="chainedUserEmail" class="chained-quiz-email " required></p>
    
     <input type="submit" id="submit-email" value="Submit" name="submit-email-btn844640736">
     </form>
            
            
            </div>
        
        ';
        
echo '<pre>';
echo strip_tags( $s,'<h2>');
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$regex = '#\<div class="chained-quiz-email"\>(.+?)\<\/div\>#s';
preg_match($regex, $s, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Comment: hello ahmm... that's kind of not the case I was looking for some regular expression or way to remove the html code. It doesn't involve actually of like hitting a button from a form.

Answer (score 0):

Using [domdocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) class

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument; 
$doc->loadHTML($s);

$thedocument = $doc->documentElement;

$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach($selector->query('//div[contains(attribute::class, "chained-quiz-email")]') as $e ) {
    // Select all child node
    $e->parentNode->removeChild($e);
}

echo $doc->saveHTML($thedocument);
```